# Php cURL with calling an API with GRAPHQL

Tags: php, curl, graphql

I am trying to call an api called [Wave](https://developer.waveapps.com) I have used cURL before but never with GRAPHQL queries. I am wondering what is wrong with the below when using cURL. I get an error **Bad Request** Below is an exmple of my code.

This is what the API cURL is

```
curl -X POST "https://reef.waveapps.com/graphql/public" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{ "query": "query { user { id defaultEmail } }" }'


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://reef.waveapps.com/graphql/public');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{ "query": "query { user { id defaultEmail } }');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);


$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer 1212121';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Any chance you could mark my answer as solved?

Answer (score 13):

For those wanting to query a GraphQL service WITHOUT a third party library, I basically took Brian's code and tested against a GraphCMS service I had already written Node.js code for. So I knew the url, authorization token, and query all worked.

```
<?php
$endpoint = "https://api-euwest.graphcms.com/v1/[[your id number here]]/master";//this is provided by graphcms
$authToken = "[[your auth token]]";//this is provided by graphcms
$qry = '{"query":"query {products(where:{status:PUBLISHED}){title,img,description,costPrice,sellPrice,quantity,sku,categories {name},brand {name}}}"}';

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$authToken;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $qry);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

?>
```

All worked good.
The auth token is a big long character string provided by GraphCMS and only needs to be passed in the header. So no real tricky authentication process - as long as you have the token.

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend using https://github.com/softonic/graphql-client, it has worked great for us.

Comment: It works well but I am using an Access token and it does not require OAuth2 not sure if you have the sem process?

Comment: Have not dealt with authentication yet, as our API is only internal.

Comment: In this library there is an helper builder that uses OAuth2 guzzle middleware. However, you could use your own guzzle middleware in the same way: https://github.com/softonic/graphql-client/blob/master/src/ClientBuilder.php#L20

Answer (score 1):

A way easier way to go about doing this is by using an API platform. I often use Postman, the platform have the functionality to give you the PHP cURL code for a GraphQL request in the GraphQl tools part of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own client passing whatever middleware you'd like:

```
$clientWithMiddleware = \MyGuzzleClientWithMiddlware::build();
$graphQLClient = new \Softonic\GraphQL\Client(
    $clientWithMiddleware,
    new \Softonic\GraphQL\ResponseBuilder()
);
```

For an example how to build a Guzzle client with middleware you can check this out:
https://github.com/softonic/guzzle-oauth2-middleware/blob/master/src/ClientBuilder.php

Answer (score 0):

If there is no authentication

You can use file_get_contents instead of curl

```
$url = http://myapi/graphql?query={me{name}}

$html =file_get_contents($url);
echo $html;
```

use json in query paramter for graphql;

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but I made this code

```
$endpoint = "https://gql.waveapps.com/graphql/public";
$authToken = ""; //Your Bearer code
$qry = '{"query": "query {user {id firstName lastName defaultEmail createdAt modifiedAt}}"}';
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$authToken;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $qry);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
  echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).